# query array content in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```js
var ConversationSchema = new Schema({
   conversationName:String,
   conversationID: String,
   participants: [
     {
       Id:String
     }
   ]
})
```

I'm trying to query the conversation schema to return every conversation where the participant array contain the id of the user i'm looking at. In node js please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to query a array of subdocuments in mongo (using example given in question)

```
// just query here
{ 'participants.Id': <value> }
```

Here is more documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/